# TotalOrderPartitioner ignores partition file location

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to do a simple sort example with `TotalOrderPartitioner`. The input is a sequence file with `IntWritable` as key and `NullWritable` as value. I want to sort based on key. The output of is a sequence file with `IntWritable` as key and `NullWritable` as value. I'm running this job in clustered environment. This is my driver class:

```
public class SortDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJobName("SORT-WITH-TOTAL-ORDER-PARTITIONER");
        job.setJarByClass(SortDriver.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
        SequenceFileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/user/client/seq-input"));
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SortMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SortReducer.class);
        job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);
        TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(conf, new Path("/user/client/partition.lst"));
        job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
        SequenceFileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
        SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressionType(job, SequenceFile.CompressionType.BLOCK);
        SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, BZip2Codec.class);
        SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/client/sorted-output"));
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(3);

        InputSampler.Sampler<IntWritable, NullWritable> sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler<>(0.1, 200);
        InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);

        boolean res = job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return res ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SortDriver(), args));
    }
}
```

`Mapper` class:

```
public class SortMapper extends Mapper<IntWritable, NullWritable, IntWritable, NullWritable>{

    @Override
    protected void map(IntWritable key, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(key, value);
    }
}
```

`Reducer` class:

```
public class SortReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, NullWritable, IntWritable, NullWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
    }
}
```

When I run this job I get:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read partitions file
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner.setConf(TotalOrderPartitioner.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/grid/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/client/appcache/application_1406784047304_0002/container_1406784047304_0002_01_000003/_partition.lst does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner.readPartitions(TotalOrderPartitioner.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner.setConf(TotalOrderPartitioner.java:88)
    ... 10 more
```

I found partition file in my home directory(`/user/client`) with name `_partition.lst`. The partition file name does not match with code: `TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(conf, new Path("/user/client/partition.lst"));`. Can anyone help me with this problem? I'm using hadoop 2.4 in HDP 2.1 distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the line:

```
TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(conf, new Path("/user/client/partition.lst"));
```

You have to replace it with:

```
TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(job.getConfiguration(), new Path("/user/client/partition.lst"));
```

since you are using

```
InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);
```

Otherwise, try replacing the last line only with:

```
InputSampler.writePartitionFile(conf, sampler);
```

But I am not sure if it works like that in the new API.

Hope it helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also found this error when I was using hadoop mapreduce and the mapreduce service had not been installed and started. After installing mapreduce and starting it, the exception disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

got this error when I had job.setNumReduceTasks(3); and was running my code in standalone mode

changed it to job.setNumReduceTasks(1) and worked fine in standalone mode